# Django: using AJAX for login, how do (should) I update a form's CSRF Token?

Tags: python, django, ajax

**Context:**

A company project I am working on is using AJAX to log a user in for certain actions on the webpage. This webpage can be viewed without logging in, but certain actions need authentication (like updating the settings of a piece of hardware). I want to preserve the form the user currently has so they don't have to re-input their changes (which I am currently doing by hiding the form and overlaying a "login" form) so refreshing the page is not an option, or at the very least, a last resort.

**The issue:**

After the login has completed, the CSRF token of the first form is now invalid and needs to be updated. This is not a question of "how do I add a CSRF token to an AJAX request", but a "how do I update it".

Django is throwing the following error after logging in: `Forbidden (CSRF token from POST incorrect.)`

**Here's what I've already tried:**

*Sending a new CSRF token for the form after logging in (server-side)*:

```py
form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    # Login the user
    user = authenticate(
        username=form.cleaned_data.get("username"),
        password=form.cleaned_data.get("password"),
    )
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Neither of these have worked
        # return JsonResponse(dict(success=True, csrfToken=request.POST.get("csrfmiddlewaretoken")))
        # return JsonResponse(dict(success=True, csrfToken=str(csrf(request)["csrf_token"])))
```

*On the client*:

```js
// From Django's AJAX documentation
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

...

// Submit the login information and then update the page's CRSF token
// This is first and is run when the user is anonymous
$.ajax({
    url: $("#login-form").attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie("csrftoken"),
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // Update the new CSRF token
        csrfToken = data["csrfToken"];
        ...

// Submit the settings form with (hopefully) an updated CSRF token
// This is second and is run when the user is authenticated
// Spoiler: it doesn't work
$.ajax({
    url: $("#settings-form").attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie("csrftoken"),
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
```

I 100% admit I don't have much experience with AJAX or CSRF Tokens, so if I am doing something wrong, it is because of my lack of experience. I haven't seen any other posts--anywhere--regarding an issue like this (99% have been the "how do I add a CSRF token" problem) but am willing to look at any that you think may be relevant.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Jules

Comment: What are your values of `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` and `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` on an environment you are debugging?

Comment: `request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"]` should contain the new csrf value after login. You might need to update the hidden csrf input in the forms too.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak They are both false.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @thebjorn in the comments of my post above, I was able to determine that I failed to update the CSRF token on the form as well.

Unfortunately, for whatever the reason I'm sure someone smarter than I knows, using the CSRF token I send back to the client on the POST request from the login form continues to throw this issue. As a work around, I'm using the `fetch` API and just pulling a new one from Django. This appears to work.

For future reference for those who find this post, here is the updated login AJAX code from above:

```js
// Store the csrf token here and update this variable
// upon user login
var csrfToken = getCookie("csrftoken");

// Submit the login information and then update the page's CRSF token
// This is first and is run when the user is anonymous
$.ajax({
    url: $("#login-form").attr("action"),
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // Update the new CSRF token
        fetch(window.location.href, {
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFTOKEN-ONLY": "True"  // Custom header
            }
        })
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data_ => {
            console.log(data_);
            csrfToken = data_["csrftoken"];
            $("#settings-form [name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(data_["csrftoken"]);
        ...
```

Thanks again to @thebjorn and to @YevgeniyKosmak for their help.

Answer (score 0):

i have an easy way :

in ajax headers :
headers: {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')},

don't forget to put the getcookie function :

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```